# MVCS pattern, When create services

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

For example  i have an app for generating reports which uses few datasources, when user request an report data shoudl be fetched from all datasources and processed - saved to file, saving for data from any datasource is done in same way. My question is how many services shoudl i create? One per datasource or one service which methods which takes datasource as additional argument? Or maybe it's better to do all fetching and saving in controler?

Answer (score 1):

What you could/should do is:

- use [repository pattern](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff649690.aspx) per each datasource
- use single service per report(s) which would aggregate data from repositories

Such design would hide data source details behind service interface, which is a good thing since the client cares about report, not data sources.

Spring already promotes such design via `@Service` and `@Repository` components.